# ¿Como obtener un número como la suma de cuatro cuadrados?

Tags: javascript

Mi pregunta esta relacionada con el **[teorema de los cuatro cuadrados de Lagrange](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_los_cuatro_cuadrados)**

Necesito una función (o una biblioteca), en el lenguaje Javascript o lenguaje parecido, que dado un numero entero positivo devuelva un arreglo con la suma de cuatro cuadrados.

Por ejemplo: para el número 61771 la factorización sería 61771 = 191² + 159² + 3² y lo que tiene que devolver (en notación json) seria [191, 159, 3]

Lo he intentado hacer. Pero el unico algoritmo que se me ocurre da como resultado 61771 = 248² + 16² + 3² + 1² + 1²  lo cual es incorrecto.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```js
function fn(n) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
  var y = Math.pow(x, 2);
  var f = [];
  while (n > 0) {
    f.push(x);
    n -= y;
    x = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
    y = Math.pow(x, 2);
  }
  return f;
}
```

Agradeceria que me explicaran.

Saludos!

Comment: mira este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524508/express-a-given-number-as-a-sum-of-four-squares

Comment: cual es la aplicacion de este algoritmo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si definimos que

- el algoritmo `converge` cuando la función retorna 4 o menos elementos
- `no converge` cuando retorna más de 4 elementos
- la `semilla` es el primer elemento que insertamos en el array

Podemos decir que al asumir que la `semilla` es el máximo cuadrado perfecto menor a N, el algoritmo en algunos casos `no converge`.

En ese caso, 61771 tiene como mayor cuadrado perfecto 248², pero el algoritmo `no converge` con esa `semilla`.

Si probamos con la `semilla` 248 `no converge` (`248² + 16² + 3² + 1² +1²`)

Si probamos con la `semilla` 247 `no converge` (`247² + 27² + 5² + 2² +2²`)

Si probamos con la `semilla` 246 `no converge`  (`246² + 35² + 5² + 2² +1²`)

Y finalmente, con la `semilla` 245 SI CONVERGE: `245² + 41² + 8² + 1²`

Mi solución, bastante a lo bruto, sería ir probando semillas, y si no converge probar de nuevo restando 1 a la semilla, hasta que converja.

```js
function fn(n,delta) {
  var n0 = n;
  var x0 = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))-delta;
  var y0 = Math.pow(x0, 2);
  var f = [];
  n -= y0;
  f.push(x0+'²');
  while (n > 0) {
    
    var x1 = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
    var y1 = Math.pow(x1, 2);
    n -= y1;
    f.push(x1+'²');
  }
  if(f.length>4) {
    return fn(n0,delta+1);
  }
  var respuesta={numero_inicial: n0, iteraciones:delta, numeros:f.join(' + ')};
  return respuesta;
}

var numero = Math.floor(100000*Math.random());
console.log(fn(numero,0));
```

¿Por qué es "a lo bruto"? Bueno, es porque en algunos casos se cumple que el número puede descomponerse en 3 cuadrados perfectos, usando una semilla aún menor que la que devuelve mi algoritmo, siempre y cuando N no tenga la forma `4^a (8 m + 7)` donde `a` y `m` son enteros. Pero ese es el llamado [Teorema de los 3 cuadrados de Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) que después demostró Gauss, y no tengo intención de ahondar tanto cuando tu pregunta se responde con 4 elementos.

Comment: como curiosidad: podría darse el caso de que no convergiera en ningún caso entre 1 y `sqrt(num)` ? De estos temas no tengo ni idea, solo es por si hubiera que indicar en tu algoritmo una salida del tipo "no converge".

Comment: Bueno, se podría poner la condición de que el segundo elemento del arreglo no pueda ser mayor a la `semilla` porque en ese caso estaríamos de vuelta en la iteración anterior. Pero el teorema de los cuatro cuadrados tiene una demostración basada en cuatro lemas que a su vez tienen su respectiva demostración. No me acuerdo de esa demostración porque la tuve que aprender a mediados de 1995 en Cálculo I, y de eso como verás ha pasado demasiado tiempo. Podría copiar y pegar una demostración de otra página, pero sería trampa.